# how to prevent tab changing without validating current tabs form fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, tabs

how to prevent tab changing without validating current tabs form fields.
i have a big signup form so i split that form in several tabs, when first tab form fields are not get validate still that time second tab should not open. i am using javascript. and its for validation it show a popup (alert) box but after clicking that box ok then it move to second field.

please help me to improve it.
here is the javascript:

```
function checkForm1() {
  // Fetching values from all input fields and storing them in variables.
  var name = document.getElementById("campus_name").value;
  var email = document.getElementById("campus_email").value;
  var password = document.getElementById("campuspwd").value;
  var phone = document.getElementById("campusphone").value;
  var address = document.getElementById("campus_address").value;

  //Check input Fields Should not be blanks.
  if (name == '' || password == '' || email == '' || phone == '') {

    alert("Fill All Fields");   

  } else{
    //Notifying error fields
    var username1 = document.getElementById("username");
    var password1 = document.getElementById("password");
    var email1 = document.getElementById("email");
    var website1 = document.getElementById("website");
    //Check All Values/Informations Filled by User are Valid Or Not.If All Fields Are invalid Then Generate alert.
    if (username1.innerHTML == 'Must be 3+ letters' || password1.innerHTML == 'Password too short' || email1.innerHTML == 'Invalid email' || website1.innerHTML == 'Invalid website') {
      alert("Fill Valid Information");
    } else {
      //Submit Form When All values are valid.
      document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
    }
  }
}
```

and this is the html code of creating tabs:

```
<div id="rootwizard" class="wizard">
  <!-- Wizard heading -->
  <div class="wizard-head">
    <ul class="bwizard-steps">
      <li id="tab1" class="active primary"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Registration Credentials</a></li>
      <li class="primary"  ><a onclick="checkForm1()" href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">College Details</a></li>
      <li class="primary"><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">College Overview</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Post html too please and yea a fiddle would be great instead!!

Comment: Were you able to read your code? What an `#Indentation`!

Comment: this is the html code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the form is not valid when i am checking for validation then disable the next and previous buttons. so that it wouldn't allow to change the tab.
And if all fields are valid then remove disable and allow normal process of tabs.

I got this answer and i hope if someone need it in future so i'll post its answer.